# Web dev novice - website appearing tiny on phone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have been creating a website as my first project getting in to HTML and CSS but for some reason the site is appearing tiny on my iPhone 5. From everything I've Googled it seems that the common problem is that images don't resize correctly but I haven't been able to find people whose website fonts and content becomes this small.

Ideally I would like the fonts to be much bigger on my phone, but from what I've read I shouldn't have to say that in a media query it should just happen.

I suspect that I may have set something in my CSS to make I behave this way accidentally but can't for the life of me figure it out.

My website link is below:
http://jacksontaylor.net/blog/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this meta tag inside your html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```